# Parentheses needed for double exclamation in chaining?

Tags: javascript

When creating a chained command, do I need to wrap the chain in parentheses when using the double exclamation, or is it implicitly handled?

For example:

```
!!jQuery.fn.jquery.match(/^1\.[0-4]/)
```

Will the above double negate "jQuery" or will it do the whole line? If the former, then I have to do this?

```
!!(jQuery.fn.jquery.match(/^1\.[0-4]/))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The . has the highest order of operations in javascript, so your first line should work fine.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table

Answer (score 1):

The member operator (the dot between properties) has the [highest precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) of any operator, so you don't need the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

According to this, `.` has a higher precedence than `!` (and anything else, actually).  Therefore, parentheses are not needed in this case.